# Disable drag text in QTextBrowser

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextbrowser

I want to enable my text in `QTextBrowser` to be selected but not to be dragged.

**Is there any way to disable dragging in** `QTextBrowser` **(or** `QTextEdit`**)?**

Please help me.

Comment: you mean readonly: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#readOnly-prop ?

Comment: `QTextBrowser` is `QTextEdit` in read-only mode by default.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#TextInteractionFlag-enum) and also `QTextEdit::drag/Enter/Leave/Move/Event`